# Let $S_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(i+1) \left ( 1 +\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n-i} \right )}$. Does $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

We define a sequence $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by
$$
S_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(i+1) \left ( 1 +\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n-i} \right )}.
$$

Clearly, $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ does not have a form of a series, so I could not use [convergence tests](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_tests).  Could you elaborate on the convergence of $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: $(S_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence that is clearly bounded below (consider $0$) and so therefore must converge.

Comment: @SAWblade It is not decreasing.

Comment: More than convergent, numerical result shows the limit equals $1$. It is easy to show $1\le \lim S_n$, and we need to show $\lim S_n\le 1$. Maybe the symmetry can help.

Comment: $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{z^{n-1}}n.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $H_n:=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1k$.  Recall that
$$H_n = \log n + \gamma + O\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $\gamma$ is a constant (a well known constant in this case). Then
$$
\begin{align}
A_n:=\sum^{n}_{k=2}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{H_{n+1-k}}\geq \frac{1}{H_{n-1}}(H_n-1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}$$

For any $0<q<1$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum^{n}_{k=2}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{H_{n+1-k}}&=\sum^{\lfloor qn\rfloor}_{k=1} + \sum^n_{k=\lfloor nq\rfloor+1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{H_{n+1-k}}\\
&\leq \Big(\frac{H_{\lfloor qn \rfloor}}{H_{n+1-\lfloor qn\rfloor}}\big) + \big(H_n-H_{\lfloor nq\rfloor}\big)\\
&\sim\frac{\log(\lfloor nq\rfloor)}{\log(n+1-\lfloor nq\rfloor)} + \log\Big(\frac{n}{\lfloor nq\rfloor}\Big)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1+\log(1/q)
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$1\leq\liminf_nA_n\leq \limsup_nA_n\leq1+\log(1/q)$$
Letting $q\rightarrow1$ yields
$$\lim_nA_n=1$$